# How to make electron work with sqlite3?

Tags: javascript, npm, sqlite, electron

I have tried everything, can't get it to work. I get this error:

[image: here is my <code>package.json</code>]

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "test",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "rebuild": "electron-rebuild -f -w sqlite3"
  },
  "repository": "https://github.com",
  "keywords": [
    "test"
  ],
  "author": "GitHub",
  "license": "CC0-1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "~1.6.2",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.5.11"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6",
    "electron-fetch": "^1.0.0-aplha4",
    "electron-handlebars": "^1.0.0",
    "electron-prebuilt": "^1.4.13",
    "electron-rebuild": "^1.5.11",
    "electron-sqlite3": "^0.0.3",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.0",
    "sqlite3": "^3.1.8"
  }
}
```

In the code I use:

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
let db = new sqlite3.Database(':memory:');
```

Any ideas how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you already run sqlite3 through electron-rebuild?

```
$ electron-rebuild -f -w sqlite3
```

or

```
$ npm rebuild
```